# Set the view name as action attribute in ASP .NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there any way to set the view file name as an attribute on top of Action ?

ex:

```
[ViewName("~/Views/CustomerInformation.cshtml")]
public ActionResult ViewCustomers()
{
    // 
}
```

purpose is to change the view file dynamically at run time.

Comment: *purpose is to change the view file dynamically at run time* can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you could override the `OnActionExecuted` method and replace the original view name that was used by the one specified in the action filter:

```
public class ViewNameAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string _viewName;
    public ViewNameAttribute(string viewName)
    {
        _viewName = viewName;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.ViewName = _viewName;
        }
    }
}
```

and then you could just return a dummy view:

```
[ViewName("~/Views/CustomerInformation.cshtml")]
public ActionResult ViewCustomers()
{
    return View();
}
```

But I wonder what the practical application of your custom action filter is when you could directly write:

```
public ActionResult ViewCustomers()
{
    return View("~/Views/CustomerInformation.cshtml");
}
```

You doesn't seem to be bringing much value with this custom action filter to what the framework already provides.

Comment: For some reason I can't explain setting the viewname as an attribute seems a bit more dev-friendly in the sense that it's more readable and communicative. I guess it helps me figure out which .cshtml is being employed right off the bat. It all boils down to personal taste of course. Thanks for pointing out this resource.

Comment: The second suggestion doesn't work if you want to call another Action (Base controller for example) but want to use the Base method view